# PHP - Can't set RAW cookie from cURL response

Tags: php, rest, cookies, curl

so I'm running into a rather unusual issue.

I've got a RESTful API I'm connecting to, which for it's SignIn method returns a response body. Within the response is an authorization token that comes in the form of a string. I then need to set that authorization string to a cookie for the system to recognize that the user is logged in.

I've written the PHP to do the cURL request, which successfully fetches back the response authorization code, however since that string contains characters like "+" and "/" I need to set a raw cookie instead of a regular one, since the http encoding will generate a cookie with "%2B" and "%2F in place of the "+" and "/".

The problem is, my setrawcookie() returns false, where the setcookie() returns true, even though I'm passing it the same parameters.

Furthermore, if I were to take the authorization string that's echo'd out by PHP and set static string with that copied auth string, the setrawcookie succeeds.

For some reason, PHP is not allowing me to create a raw cookie with string data from a cURL request. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

```
$data = array("Username" => $_POST['Username'], "Password" => $_POST['Password']);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);   



    $ch = curl_init('https://cloudhub.quivers.com/api/v1/SignIn/Signin');                                                        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );                                                                                      

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);

setrawcookie("AuthToken", $result, 0, "/", "www.quivers.com", 1);
```

In this instance, setrawcookie() fails but setcookie() works.

Response body looks like this: -

```
1DEbKeyynVTbXeRJ2i5j2+UgwgmuD17VgQtFbzg2LBLmXMLDUY5t9YV2wdqQOcycZumuzqHH3AJ8e8I3nao0VPBuELAoGa6T27jwgAAizCoSyu0maPnXzfFbYkMnOPRhak9/6fQMqspg...
```

Comment: yes, but if you're sending out a raw `+` in there, and the receiving side DECODES that string, then `+` becomes a space and corrupts your string. As far setcookie goes, it couldn't care less where that string comes from. a string's a string. setcookie has no idea it came from curl.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the curl cookie into a file. It can be done like this:

```
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
```

Now the cookie information (session) will be stored in the file.